# Push array based on JSON value and key

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON array that I am attempting to manipulate with jQuery to push a generated array `options` based on the `group_id` and children `id` value. I am seeking a way to identify these keys and values to initiate the push, possibly through iteration.

For example, if I wanted to insert where `group_id` had a value of 1 and where children had an ID of 1, my created array would be inserted into options.

```
var data = $.parseJSON(array);

var options = [];
    var item1 = {
            "option_id": 1,
            "option": "",
            "value": "",
        },
        item2 = {
            "option_id": 2,
            "option": "",
            "value": "",
        },
    };
options.push(item1, item2);

var group = data.filter(function(data) { return data.group_id === 1; });
var child = group.filter(function(children) { return children.id === 1; });

child.options = options;
```

My starting array `data` would be like so:

```
[
  {
    "group_id": 1,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "options": []
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "options": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "group_id": 2,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "options": []
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "options": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The resulting array would be:

```
[
  {
    "group_id": 1,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "options": [
          {
            "option_id": 1,
            "option": "",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "option_id": 2,
            "option": "",
            "value": ""
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "options": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "group_id": 2,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "options": []
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "options": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: You forgot to add the actual code you're having issues with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using the following.

```
$.each(data, function(key, item){
    if (item.group_id == 1)
    {
        $.each(item.children, function(key, item){
            if (item.id == 1)
            {
                item.options = [];
                item.options.push(options);
            }
        });
    }
});
```